# show $ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (4\arctan (e^x)-\pi)dx=0$ without calculating

Tags: calculus, integration

Show
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  (4\arctan (e^x)-\pi)dx=0$$
without calculating.

I thought we should show that the integrand is odd, but I'm having trouble showing it.

If $f(x)=4\arctan (e^x)-\pi$ we need to show that $f(-x)=-f(x)$

so $f(-x)=4\arctan (e^{-x})-\pi$ and I'm not really see how to continue...

Comment: $\arctan(x) + \arctan(\frac1{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @Nicholas exactly what I was missing, thanks! Do you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\arctan(x) + \arctan(\frac1{x}) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Which can be derived by considering a right angle triangle.